# why {%extends %} , {%block body_block%},{%endblock%} seen in webpage in browser?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EISCJ.png) here {%extends %} and {%block body_block%},{%endblock %} are seen but they shouldn't .How to fix this?

Comment: Because the template was not rendered. Show us your view code (as text, not as an image)!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KMogaOBunvouie6OQkCs7IXsTNnS-ioE

Comment: Mr . klaus d. Check out the googledrive link . I have index.html under templates directory and join it to BASE_DIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{%extends %} means that you are using Django's template extending. So you need a base.html file to extends from. For example, you could create a file base.html like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>XXX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body_block %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

then, in your original file, change like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
    <h1>Hello ClassBased View</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

then the 'body_block' part will fill in the '{% body_block %}' part of base.html.  [See more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#id1)